# Google Drive Android API - Is there any way to open a Drive file through a link?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-forms, google-drive-android-api

I know that you can open files that are either within the user's Drive or through a dialog - but is there anyway to open files that are shared to those who have the link? I'm trying to implement functionality where form submission in an app can be added to a shared spreadsheet somewhere. It's best to be shared through a link so edits can be anonymous.

I know that Google Forms is an option, but I haven't found much information on how to do that programatically, and it seems slightly more difficult. Any resources on Google Drive or Google Forms through Android would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a file by its DriveId, even when the file is public. Once your application has loaded that file at least once, you'll have access the file by a Query.

I found an example of how to retrieve the metadata of file by id in the following reference: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/RetrieveMetadataActivity.java